# Issue looping through data when response in null using curl

Tags: php, curl

Am using curl to fetch data from a payment gateway. Am writing some logic inside the curl function whereby when the response is null,, I want to continue trying for 5 more times reaching out to the payment gateway inside the curl function until the status changes but it aint working

**Curl Function**

```
 public function global_Curl_payStat($data, $url, $try = 1)
    {
        //dd($_ENV['API_ENDPOINT_NGINX_IP'] . '/' . $url);
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, ($_ENV['API_ENDPOINT_NGINX_IP'] . '/' . $url));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        //Prevents usage of a cached version of the URL
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);
        //Listen for HTTP errors
        $statusCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        //dd($statusCode); 
        $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
        dd($response);
        curl_close($ch);

        if($response == null && $try < 5) {
                //Wait a 3 seconds before trying again
                sleep(3);
                return $this->global_Curl($data, $url, ++$try);
        }

        return $response;
    }
```

**Function calling the curl function below**

```
//Set maximum execution time
    ini_set('max_execution_time ', 75);
    set_time_limit(75);
    //Loop through the code 3 times
    for($try=1; $try<=3; $try++) {
        sleep(15);
        $payStat = $this->global_Curl_payStat($data, 'api/payment/status')->data;
         //Call the curl function below
        //$payStat = $this->global_Curl($data, 'api/payment/status?cachebuster='. microtime(true))->data;
        var_dump($payStat);
        dd($payStat);
        if ($payStat->status === 1) {
            return 'true';
        }
    }
```

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: @Nick When I hit the gateway I get the response back containing the required data,, but on subsequent hits,, I get null response,, now I  check if the response is null I should continue hitting the payment gateway for 5 more times until the payment response is back

Comment: Yes, that's what your code looks like it should do. But what is it not doing?

Comment: @Nick Am still getting the response as null even after the 5th time...

Comment: Have you looked at the output of `curl_error()`?

Comment: If your `global_Curl_payStat()` function the retry is calling `global_Curl()` - is that correct?

Comment: @Nick Let me check,, will get back to you after a while..

Comment: @Nick  No errors

Comment: @NigelRen Sure,, never saw that bug,, I have rectified it,, What about while calling `global_Curl_payStat()` should I add 3 parameters